# What happens when fork() in a condition?

Tags: c, fork

Can anyone give me the output(with an explanation) of this code?
Thank you...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h> 

int main() 
{ 
    if (fork() && (!fork())) { 
        if (fork() || fork()) {
            fork(); 
        } 
    } 
    printf("Friend\n");
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running it?

Comment: The output at least you can get from running it.

Comment: First, read the man page for fork(). Then wrap your head around the fact that it returns twice; once zero and once with the pid of the child. Then maybe add in some more print statements. On my machine it prints "Friend" seven times. I'm not sure if this deterministic -- does it matter if the zero or the pid is returned first? Think about those conditionals.

Comment: Are you trying to test us?  Have you tried to write (and test) a simpler example?  Have you read the man page of `fork(2)`?  All the answers are in the man page.  Testing your sample and telling you what is happening with such logical tests requires time, and you have not shown how much of the time required you have expent in devising such code.  Just try to put some traces (by calls to `printf(3)`) run your sample, and see what happens.  You'll probably get the truth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before go into the code it is better to understand the what is fork() system call

fork() system call creates a new process by the 'parent' and the newly created process called as 'child' process

child process is returns 0 and parent returns positive integer when fork is sucess

That's the clue here

So all two process work concurrently from that program counter onwards...

in here fork() is in the if condition and it is bit tricky as well when guessing the output

1. first fork() creates new C1 -> 0
2. second fork() creates new C2 -> !0 -> 1

so first condition is statisfied by C2 (which parent positive integer and c2's 0)  but not statified by either parent or child C1 so other forks are not going to work

then C2 go into the other if condition and maked another two forks

```
            C2
          /    \
         C2     C3
       /   \   /  \
      C2   c4  c3  c5
```

Then all created processes (including parent) prints the "Friend" output 7 times

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is that the parent will do something and the child will do else.  But continue reading...

Well, I just modified lightly your code into this, and you'll get all the process hierarchy from the output of your program, and the answers to your question:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h> 

static pid_t my_fork() /* tracing is your friend! :) */
{
    pid_t chld = fork();
    if (chld > 0) {
        /* only the parent shows this */
        printf("[pid=%d, child=%d] forked!\n",
                getpid(), chld);
    }
    return chld;
}

int main() 
{ 
    /* print our pid, so we know the root of the hierarchy */
    printf("[pid=%d] Hello, world\n", getpid());

    /* do the embarrasing work */
    if (my_fork() && (!my_fork())) { 
        if (my_fork() || my_fork()) {
            my_fork(); 
        } 
    } 

    pid_t pid;
    int status;

    /* We do wait(2)'s while there are children to be waited for. 
     * it's a good thing to wait for children before ending. */
    while((pid = wait(&status)) >= 0) {
        printf("[pid=%d, child=%d]: child ended with status=%d\n",
                getpid(), pid, status);
    }
    
    /* we print the message when no more children are alive */
    printf("[pid=%d]: Hello friend!\n", getpid());

    return 0; 
}
```

and this produces

```
$ pru
[pid=72699] Hello, world
[pid=72699, child=72700] forked!
[pid=72699, child=72701] forked!
[pid=72700]: Hello friend!
[pid=72701, child=72702] forked!
[pid=72703]: Hello friend!
[pid=72699, child=72700]: child ended with status=0
[pid=72702, child=72703] forked!
[pid=72702, child=72705] forked!
[pid=72702, child=72703]: child ended with status=0
[pid=72705]: Hello friend!
[pid=72704]: Hello friend!
[pid=72701, child=72704] forked!
[pid=72701, child=72704]: child ended with status=0
[pid=72702, child=72705]: child ended with status=0
[pid=72702]: Hello friend!
[pid=72701, child=72702]: child ended with status=0
[pid=72701]: Hello friend!
[pid=72699, child=72701]: child ended with status=0
[pid=72699]: Hello friend!
```

and this is the hierarchy:

```
[pid=72699] (says Hello, world, just starting)
  +-[pid=72700] (created in first fork() call of pid=72699)
  `-[pid=72701] (created in second fork() call of pid=72699)
     +-[pid=72702] (created in third fork() call of pid=72701)
     |  +-[pid=72703] (created in fourth fork() call of pid=72702)
     |  `-[pid=72705] (created in fifth fork() call of pid=72702)
     `-[pid=7204] (created in fourth fork() call of pid=72701)
```

(of course, the hierarchy will be different if you run out of processes, and `fork(2)` fails because of lack of system resources)

Finally, you'll probably get worried about why the message

```
[pid=72703]: Hello friend!
```

appears before the message

```
[pid=72702, child=72703] forked!
```

but that's the amazing world of multitasking.  The message is printed after `fork(2)` has return, so both messages are printed by different processes, and so, they can be scheduled in any order, so the child starts and prints its message before the parent has a chance to print who is his child.  That's completely normal.

## NOTE

You have to be aware that `fork()` returns `-1` in case of error, which evaluates in a boolean test as `true`, just like the parent's result.  So if you use freely the return codes from `fork(2)` for boolean expressions, the parent will receive `true` or any error that happens for `fork()` to fail (well, they are scarce, but they are possible on a loaded system).  Just save the result code of `fork()` and check first for errors, then you are free to use any boolean expression you want on it.

The source code above can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/mojadita/so/tree/master/60226577)